# Store Custom Class in DataGridView Column

Tags: vb.net, object, datagridview, vb.net-2010

How do I store an object (class) with a DataGridView row?  I cannot set the `DataGridView.DataSource to the List(Of Class)` because the class has properties that are classes.

Perhaps I am wrong, but something like:

```
    Dim objObject As New Person
    objObject = DataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value
```

Seems cleaner (and more desirable) than:

```
    Dim intId As Integer
    intId = DataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value
    For Each obj As Object In lstObject
        If obj.ID = intId Then
            objObject = obj
        End If
    Next
```

I have searched around, and it seems as though I may have to create a custom DataGridViewColumn for this.  Is that the case, or is there some easier/built-in way?

Although perhaps I am over-thinking it, and should just go with the second method.

Comment: The first thing to determine is what you actually expect to see.  What properties does this class have and how do you expect the grid to represent each of them?

Comment: I have the grid already displaying everything I need.  The problem is that when a row is selected, I have to loop through the form's List(Of Class) to find which object that row ultimately represents.

Comment: No looping necessary.  The DataBoundItem property of the row contains the list item backing that row.

Comment: That's the problem: there is no DataBoundItem.  Because the class has properties that are classes, I cannot simply bind the list to the datagridview.  I have to manually loop through and add the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest three possible options:

1. Create a Dictionary with the rows as the keys and the source items as the values.
2. Assign the source items to the Tag properties of the corresponding rows.
3. Create a wrapper class that exposes the appropriate properties regardless of how deep they are and then bind a list of those.